# filter records based on a relationship | Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class PodcastPlatform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    badge_path = models.FilePathField(path = settings.BADGES_DIR, unique = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Podcast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created', '-updated']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PodcastLink(models.Model):
    podcast_platform = models.ForeignKey(PodcastPlatform, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField(max_length = 400, verbose_name = 'URL')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['podcast_platform__name']
        unique_together = ['podcast_platform', 'podcast']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.podcast_platform.name

    def get_badge_url(self):
        return static(re.search('img/.{0,}', self.podcast_platform.badge_path).group())
```

I want to filter the instances of the `Podcast` model where they have at least one link or a related instance of the `PodcastLink` model.
To do it, I did the following:

```
Podcast.objects.filter(podcastlink__gte = 1)
```

Returning the following QuerySet:

```
<QuerySet [<Podcast: Libero tenetur>, <Podcast: Libero tenetur>, <Podcast: Libero tenetur>, <Podcast: Assumenda iusto>, <Podcast: Assumenda iusto>, <Podcast: Assumenda iusto>, <Podcast: Assumenda iusto>, <Podcast: Explicabo>, <Podcast: Explicabo>, <Podcast: Explicabo>, <Podcast: Explicabo>, <Podcast: Explicabo>]>
```

I get the expected result, but instead I notice that the instances are repeating... Try the following and in the same way I got the same result (repeated instances):

```
Podcast.objects.filter(Q(podcastlink__gte = 1))
```

Why do I get repeated instances? as i understand this should not happen... plus it's weird...

Comment: you're querying the podcasts linked to a podcast link where the podcastlink.id is greater than one. you're not counting anything... The multiple items are caused by the reverse relationship query which creates an inner join (as multiple podcastlinks can reference the same podcast, they appear multiple times in the evaluated join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have `related_name='podcastlink'` on `PodcastLink.podcast` or some logic that sets it automatically, otherwise your code should not work.

`Podcast.objects.filter(podcastlink__gte=1)`. Does not make any sens. `podcastlink` is a relation not a number. I guess it works by chance with `podcastlink__gte=1` but wouldn't work with `podcastlink__gte=2`. To test existence of a relation you should rather use `podcastlink__isnull=False`:

```
Podcast.objects.filter(podcastlink__isnull=False)
```

However, this query will join `Podcast` and `PodcastLink` and return one entry for each combination. As you can have many `PodcastLink` per `Podcast`, you may get duplicates of `Podcast`. To avoid these duplicates, use `distinct().

```
Podcast.objects.filter(podcastlink__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Another approach is to actually count the number of links per podcast:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Podcast.objects.annotate(nb_links=Count('podcastlink')).filter(nb_links__gte=1)
```

In this case, you don't need to use `distinct()` because you aggregated the `PodcastLink` as a counter in `Podcast`. Using this method, you can also now decide to filter `Podcast` having at least 2 links as well if you want:

```
Podcast.objects.annotate(nb_links=Count('podcastlink')).filter(nb_links__gte=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and above all for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct()` to get unique instances. You probably also want to filter on the count:

```
Podcast.objects.filter(podcastlink__count__gte = 1).distinct()
```